# How does the diffusers progress bar work?

Tags: tqdm, diffusers

I'm upscaling an image using `StableDiffusionUpscalePipeline`, but the second timestamp does not appear to be total estimated duration after all. What is it then and how to get a useful estimate?

```
Loading pipeline components...: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 6/6 [00:01<00:00,  3.62it/s] 
 52%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▉                                                                      | 39/75 [4:26:46<4:19:26, 432.40s/it]
```

> `tqdm` uses smart algorithms to predict the remaining time and to
> skip unnecessary iteration displays, which allows for a negligible
> overhead in most cases.

I'll have to dive into that code and see if there's a more conservative estimate, but there's probably an expert here who's already done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 55%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▊                                                                  | 41/75 [4:41:20<4:06:17, 434.63s/it]
```

It's "time spent < time left". I feel mildly embarrassed.